# Boosting relevance, based on absolute numerical closeness

Tags: solr, lucene

In my Solr scheme, I have a numeric field that stores a color value (out of, say 65535). How can I make so that when I search for a particular color, the search relevance gets boosted, depending on how close (in absolute value) the particular search is to the asked value?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [function queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#div) to calculate the closeness and boost the value.

e.g. `div(x,65535)` which will generate a value of 1 if exact and less values depending on the closeness.

You can check for the other queries as well to factor the boost accordingly.

And [boost the results](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Field_Based_Boosting)  `q={!boost b=div(x,65535)}text:supervillians`

Answer (score 1):

together with the function queries, you can use the `recip` function for calculating boost factor from the color distance http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#recip

Example:

```
recip(div(x,65535),1,10000,10000)
```